# onCreateDialog in the general dialog fragment class returns null whenever I try to fetch the arguments which I set in my calling activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, dialogfragment

This is the general Dialog Fragment class from where I set the arguments into the bundle

```
public class GeneralDialogFragment extends BaseDialogFragment<GeneralDialogFragment.OnDialogFragmentClickListener> {


    public interface OnDialogFragmentClickListener {
        public void onClicked(GeneralDialogFragment dialogFragment);

        public void onCancelClicked(GeneralDialogFragment dialogFragment);

    }


    public static GeneralDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String message) {
        GeneralDialogFragment dialog = new GeneralDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title  ", title);
        args.putString("message", message);
        dialog.setArguments(args);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(getArguments().getString("title"))
                .setMessage(getArguments().getString("message"))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create();
    }


}
```

This is how I am calling it in the activity

```
GeneralDialogFragment generalDialogFragment = new GeneralDialogFragment();
                    generalDialogFragment.newInstance("Test", "Its working good");
                    generalDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

But I get a null pointer exception on onCreateDialog during setTitle(getArguments().getString("title"))

Comment: How did this even compile? You don't return a Dialog except when `bundle == null`

Comment: Oh sorry I put the wrong code. How about now?

Comment: You're not using `newInstance()` correctly. That method _returns_ a `GeneralDialogFragment` instance with the arguments set. It doesn't set the arguments on an existing instance. You need to assign that return to your `generalDialogFragment`, instead of directly instantiating an instance with `new` there. That is, `GeneralDialogFragment generalDialogFragment = GeneralDialogFragment.newInstance("Test", "Its working good");`.

Comment: Thanks Mike for you help. I still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `newInstance` is static, you don't need to create an object to reference it.
You should call `newInstance` and get the reference to the Dialog:

```
GeneralDialogFragment generalDialogFragment = GeneralDialogFragment.newInstance("Test", "Its working good");
generalDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Comment: Thanks Juan. Made the changes. Worked well.

Answer (score 1):

As Juan Cruz Soler says, one problem is in how you are using `newInstance()`. There is also a second problem, however.

Inside `newInstance()` you have this line:

> ```
> args.putString("title  ", title);
> ```

You then try to read the title out of the arguments `Bundle` with this line in `onCreateDialog()`:

> ```
> .setTitle(getArguments().getString("title"))
> ```

This won't work because your keys don't match. Even though it's just whitespace, `"title  "` and `"title"` are not the same string. Delete the spaces from `"title  "` in your `putString()` call, and this will be fixed.

Comment: Thank you Ben for pointing that out. I had not seen that. Appreciate your help